# Increase the maximum line numbers of a page

Tags: line-numbering

I am trying to achieve an ieee draft to meet the requirements: Double spacing, single-column format, 12 point font, 1 inch margins and no more than 25 lines of text per page.

I am using the following packages and can meet most of them. However, LaTeX automatically sets the number of lines in my page to 23, according to the space I defined. Currently my draft is too long and I have to cut it down. I am wondering how I could increase the maximum line number from 23 to 25, without affecting margin/font/double spacing?

Here is my detailed code:

```
\documentclass[journal,12 pt,draftclsnofoot,onecolumn]{IEEEtran}
\usepackage[margin=1 in]{geometry}
\usepackage{kantlipsum}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{epsfig}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage{amsmath, amssymb,theorem, multirow, cite}

\pagestyle{empty}

\raggedbottom

\usepackage{color}

\pagestyle{empty}

\begin{document}

\title{How can I increase the number of lines in each page, without affecting margin/font/double spacing}

\maketitle

\begin{spacing}{2.0}

\setlength{\abovedisplayskip}{0cm}

\setlength{\belowdisplayskip}{0cm}

\begin{abstract} 
\end{abstract}

\end{spacing}
\end{document}
```

Comment: unrelated but don't load epsfig!!!

Comment: `\begin{spacing}{1.9}` gets you 25 lines with no other changes. I don't see how you're going to change the number of lines on a page without changing any margins, font size, or line spacing. There's nothing else in the equation, so to speak.

Comment: The usual way to achieve "doublespacing" with the `setspace` package is to issue the command `\doublespacing` (and not use the `spacing` *environment*). With `\doublespacing` in effect, you get about 27 or 28 lines per page, which should be more than enough for your needs. If you must have exactly 25 lines per page, use `\setstretch{1.9}`.

Comment: Hi Mike Renfro, if I use \begin{spacing}{1.9}, does that mean it is not double-space any more?

Comment: Hi Mico, you are right. If I use \doublespacing, I will have 27 to 28 lines per page, which is not allowed.I did try \setstretch{1.9} but it seems no difference with my current format.

Comment: If you use `\setstretch{<some factor>}`, be sure not to use one of the `spacing` environments as well.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not completely sure what you're going for here, because the number of lines per page is a factor of the font size, line spacing, and margins—without changing those there's no magic way to fit more lines beside making the paper bigger.

You, as the one typesetting, have to decide what "double spacing" means and how to weigh the different (and possibly conflicting) instructions you've been given.

Its also worth noting that your document does not actually obey the 1in margins exactly anyway, because double spacing as you've specified it does not exactly fit on one page, so you'll have very slightly uneven top and bottom margins. (do `\usepackage{showframe}` to see where the margins should be.)

I don't know how IEEE works, but why doesn't their package (which already changes the linespacing and stuff) work for them? Seems like it should work out of the box?

Here's an example changing the linespacing very slightly to get 25 lines per page:

```
\documentclass[journal,12 pt,draftclsnofoot,onecolumn]{IEEEtran}
\usepackage[margin=1 in]{geometry}
\usepackage{kantlipsum}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{epsfig}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage{amsmath, amssymb,theorem, multirow, cite}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{showframe}

\pagestyle{empty}

\raggedbottom

\usepackage{color}

\pagestyle{empty}

\begin{document}

\title{How can I increase the number of lines in each page, without affecting margin/font/double spacing}

\maketitle

\begin{spacing}{1.9}

% \flushbottom % if you want exactly 1in margins, this will stretch your paragraphs and lines (depending on how IEEEtran is built) to make that happen

\setlength{\abovedisplayskip}{0cm}

\setlength{\belowdisplayskip}{0cm}

\begin{abstract} 
\end{abstract}

\lipsum[1-10]

\end{spacing}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

In the IEEEtran class you can use `\CLASSINPUTbaselinestretch` but *before* the document:

```
\newcommand{\CLASSINPUTbaselinestretch}{2.2}
\documentclass[journal,draftclsnofoot,onecolumn]{IEEEtran}
\usepackage{kantlipsum}
\begin{document}
\kant[1-30]
\end{document}
```

Note that using CLASSINPUT controls can result in documents that are not compliant with the IEEE’s standards. On the other hand, you do not need fix margins nor the `12pt` option, since these are the defaults for the draft modes.